# Xcode autolayout storyboard preview does not show container views

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

Xcode's excellent autolayout storyboard preview panel ..

(to bring it up: click the "double circle icon" to bring up an assistant editor. Click the popup menu which defaults to "Automatic", select "Preview" for the autolayout preview engine. Down the bottom select screen sizes...)

... in fact **does not render container views**;

it just renders the shape correctly per the constraints (which is terrific as far as it goes), and leaves it gray, and adds a label "Container".

[image]

In fact,

- is there a way to have it render the content of container views?
- can you somehow select a container view, and have it preview "just" that container view, maybe?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now, there is no way to "preview" container's content view inside the container view. The only way is to run the app. :(

Comment: I guess that's all there is to it!  Cheers Dinesh